# Display intermediate values of variables in a Python Script using Sublime Text (or any text editor)

Tags: python

Can I display values of variables in a Python script using sublime text just like how MATLAB lets you display values of variables from the workspace on the command window?

Comment: https://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/

Comment: you mean step through the code?